# Unusual compiler message in gcc-8.2

Tags: c++

The following piece of code works as expected but gives an odd looking message during compilation.  Not sure what to make of it, but just trying to understand what GCC is trying to convey.  Is it an error or just a GCC oddity?  This is not happening in gcc-10.2

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <optional>

template < typename T >
struct Optional : public std::optional < T >
{
    using impl_t = std::optional < T >;
    using impl_t::impl_t;

    constexpr inline friend bool operator == (Optional const & lhs, Optional const & rhs)
    {
        return static_cast < impl_t const & >(lhs) == static_cast < impl_t const & >(rhs);
    }

    template < typename U, typename = std::enable_if_t < std::is_convertible_v < U, T > > >
    constexpr inline friend bool operator == (const Optional& lhs, U const & rhs)
    {
        return lhs.has_value() && static_cast < impl_t const & >(lhs) == rhs;
    }

};

[[maybe_unused]]
auto triggers_unusual_compile_warning()
{
    constexpr std::array < Optional < int32_t >, 4 > c{{1, 2, 3, std::nullopt}};
    if (std::count(c.begin(), c.end(), std::nullopt) != 1)
        throw std::runtime_error("WTH!!!");
};

int main()
{
    triggers_unusual_compile_warning();
}
```

That small program triggers the following message

```
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-8.2.0/include/c++/8.2.0/bits/predefined_ops.h: In instantiation of 'bool __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_equals_val<_Value>::operator()(_Iterator) [with _Iterator = const Optional<int>*; _Value = const std::nullopt_t]':
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-8.2.0/include/c++/8.2.0/bits/stl_algo.h:3194:12:   required from 'typename std::iterator_traits<_Iterator>::difference_type std::__count_if(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _Predicate) [with _InputIterator = const Optional<int>*; _Predicate = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_equals_val<const std::nullopt_t>; typename std::iterator_traits<_Iterator>::difference_type = long int]'
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-8.2.0/include/c++/8.2.0/bits/stl_algo.h:4082:29:   required from 'typename std::iterator_traits<_Iterator>::difference_type std::count(_IIter, _IIter, const _Tp&) [with _IIter = const Optional<int>*; _Tp = std::nullopt_t; typename std::iterator_traits<_Iterator>::difference_type = long int]'
<source>:29:52:   required from here
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-8.2.0/include/c++/8.2.0/optional:1371:5: note: candidate 1: 'constexpr bool std::operator==(const std::optional<_Tp>&, std::nullopt_t) [with _Tp = int]'
     operator==(const optional<_Tp>& __lhs, nullopt_t) noexcept
     ^~~~~~~~
<source>:12:34: note: candidate 2: 'constexpr bool operator==(const Optional<int>&, const Optional<int>&)'
     constexpr inline friend bool operator == (Optional const & lhs, Optional const & rhs)
                                  ^~~~~~~~
ASM generation compiler returned: 0
In file included from <source>:4:
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-8.2.0/include/c++/8.2.0/bits/predefined_ops.h: In instantiation of 'bool __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_equals_val<_Value>::operator()(_Iterator) [with _Iterator = const Optional<int>*; _Value = const std::nullopt_t]':
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-8.2.0/include/c++/8.2.0/bits/stl_algo.h:3194:12:   required from 'typename std::iterator_traits<_Iterator>::difference_type std::__count_if(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _Predicate) [with _InputIterator = const Optional<int>*; _Predicate = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_equals_val<const std::nullopt_t>; typename std::iterator_traits<_Iterator>::difference_type = long int]'
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-8.2.0/include/c++/8.2.0/bits/stl_algo.h:4082:29:   required from 'typename std::iterator_traits<_Iterator>::difference_type std::count(_IIter, _IIter, const _Tp&) [with _IIter = const Optional<int>*; _Tp = std::nullopt_t; typename std::iterator_traits<_Iterator>::difference_type = long int]'
<source>:29:52:   required from here
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-8.2.0/include/c++/8.2.0/optional:1371:5: note: candidate 1: 'constexpr bool std::operator==(const std::optional<_Tp>&, std::nullopt_t) [with _Tp = int]'
     operator==(const optional<_Tp>& __lhs, nullopt_t) noexcept
     ^~~~~~~~
<source>:12:34: note: candidate 2: 'constexpr bool operator==(const Optional<int>&, const Optional<int>&)'
     constexpr inline friend bool operator == (Optional const & lhs, Optional const & rhs)
                                  ^~~~~~~~
Execution build compiler returned: 0
```

Comment: There seems to be something missing from the message, as it contains no errors, only supporting notes that typically accompany errors.

Comment: You forgot the part of the error message that says what the error is. Ambiguous comparison between Optional and nullopt_t. The system can't decide whether to treat the Optional as std::optional and compare the std::optional to nullopt_t. Or whether to convert the nullopt_t to Optional and then compare the two Optionals.

Comment: There is no error.  This compiles and works as expected.  I just get this message during compilation

Comment: Looks like the error/warning is protected by some -W* flag, but the accompanying notes are not. There used to be a few of those bugs, most have been fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with the code is that the equality operator is ambiguous. A `std::nullopt` [can be converted](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/optional) to a `std::optional`.
So, by instantiating a `operator==` when you call `std::count`, the compiler cannot choose between the [operator==](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/operator_cmp) from the library and your `operator==` declared as

```
constexpr inline friend bool operator == (Optional const & lhs, Optional const & rhs)
```

How exactly to solve this problem depends on the details you have in mind. For example, if you add an explicit comparison with `std::nullopt_t`

```
constexpr inline friend bool operator == (Optional const & lhs, std::nullopt_t const & rhs)
    {
        return static_cast < impl_t const & >(lhs) == static_cast < impl_t const & >(rhs);
    }
```

you force the compiler to choose your more-specific implementation, and the error disappears.

But of course, a good solution depends on what you have in mind.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, that code compiles and works as expected.  Just this extra annoying message.  std::optional has a overload of operator == for std::nullopt_t.  So this is not due to the operator ==

I think the issue is somewhere inside std::count

Comment: @zrb Check the code with godbolt [here](https://godbolt.org/z/sMK5aK) It does not compile neither with gcc (any version >=7.1) nor with clang.

Comment: Thanks.  It is rejected with -pedantic, so I need to find an alternative way to implement it